# How can I do that the setOnTouchListener() method works only for a custom view

Tags: android

I have the `Rectangle` and `Larger_Rectangle` classes. Now I want to do that when I touch only on the rectangle object from the `rectangle` class as the result I see other rectangle object from the `Larger_Rectangle` class.

**Rectangle.class**

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
Paint paint;
Rectangle(Context context) {
super(context);
paint = new Paint();
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawRect(10,30,50,70,paint);
}
}
```

**The Larger_Rectangle class**

```
public class Larger_Rectangle extends View {
Paint paint;
Larger_Rectangle(Context context) {
super(context);
paint = new Paint();
}
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
canvas.drawRect(60,100,120,150,paint);
}
}
```

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Rectangle rectangle;
Larger_Rectangle larger_rectangle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
super.onCreate(bundle);
rectangle = new Rectangle(this);
setContentView(rectangle);
rectangle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        larger_rectangle = new Larger_Rectangle(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(larger_rectangle);

        return true;
    }
});
}
}
```

I want when I touch only on the rectangle object I can see the larger_rectangle object, but in here when I touch anywhere in the touch screen I see the larger_rectangle object.

Comment: Is your small rectangle stretched and has height and width same as that of the device screen?

Comment: It may be your layout problem.check it first

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you had views are supposed to be a class...

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Rectangle rectangle;
Larger_Rectangle larger_rectangle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    rectangle = new Rectangle(this);
    setContentView(rectangle);
    rectangle.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            larger_rectangle = new Larger_Rectangle(getApplicationContext());
            setContentView(larger_rectangle);

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle extends View {
Paint paint;

Rectangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(10,30,50,70,paint);
}
```

}

and finally Large_Rectangle.java...

```
public class Larger_Rectangle extends View {
Paint paint;

Larger_Rectangle(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(60,100,120,150,paint);
}
```

}

Comment: Consider a button. You can go to other activity when you press only on the button and not elsewhere. When I run your code and when I touch elsewhere also, I see the its effect again. while I want when I touch only on the `rectangle` object I see its effect.